# How do I determine with powershell the PIDs of incognito chrome tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, private-browsing

As per [this website](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-run-google-chrome-in-incognito-mode-from-the-command-line-or-a-shortcut/) the way to start chome in incognito on the command line is

> & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -incognito

(edited to work in powershell)

I can get a list of all my chrome process Pids and command line with the one liner:

> Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'chrome.exe'" | Select ProcessId, CommandLine|
>    fl *|clip

However, none of the incognito processes, whether s=launched by Ctrl+Shift+N or command line have that command line argument:

```
ProcessId   : 29600
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end

ProcessId   : 12588
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=crashpad-handler 
              "--user-data-dir=C:\Users\justin.dearing\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data" /prefetch:7 
              --monitor-self-annotation=ptype=crashpad-handler 
              "--database=C:\Users\justin.dearing\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Crashpad" 
              "--metrics-dir=C:\Users\justin.dearing\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data" 
              --url=https://clients2.google.com/cr/report --annotation=channel= --annotation=plat=Win64 
              --annotation=prod=Chrome --annotation=ver=63.0.3239.132 
              --initial-client-data=0x1e4,0x1e8,0x1ec,0x1e0,0x1f0,0x7ffb01b85720,0x7ffb01b85760,0x7ffb01b85738

ProcessId   : 30604
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=watcher --main-thread-id=23004 
              --on-initialized-event-handle=616 --parent-handle=620 /prefetch:6

ProcessId   : 29940
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=gpu-process 
              --field-trial-handle=1456,10619170367124795314,15493821474693019085,131072 --gpu-vendor-id=0x8086 
              --gpu-device-id=0x193a --gpu-driver-vendor="Intel Corporation" --gpu-driver-version=22.20.16.4749 
              --gpu-driver-date=7-24-2017 --gpu-secondary-vendor-ids=0x102b --gpu-secondary-device-ids=0x0533 
              --service-request-channel-token=2E7DF9AEE477D14FE59C25335C71A2CC --mojo-platform-channel-handle=1560 
              --ignored=" --type=renderer " /prefetch:2

ProcessId   : 35036
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=utility 
              --field-trial-handle=1456,10619170367124795314,15493821474693019085,131072 --lang=en-US 
              --service-sandbox-type=utility --service-request-channel-token=EA3B8A022A6691EC43DEF92EA41799E3 
              --mojo-platform-channel-handle=3796 --ignored=" --type=renderer " /prefetch:8

ProcessId   : 9688
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check  
              "data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3Chead%3E%3C/head%3E%3Cbody%3E%3Cstyle%3Ebody%7Bmargin:25px;font:16px%20ca
              libri,'segoe%20ui'%7D%3C/style%3E%3Ch3%3EChrome%20script%20debugging%20in%20Visual%20Studio%20is%20enable
              d%3C/h3%3E%3Cul%3E%3Cli%3ESet%20breakpoints%20in%20JavaScript/TypeScript%20in%20Visual%20Studio%3C/li%3E%
              3Cli%3EAutomatically%20break%20on%20script%20errors%3C/li%3E%3Cli%3EOpening%20developer%20tools%20in%20Ch
              rome%20stops%20the%20script%20debugging%20session%3C/li%3E%3C/ul%3E%3Ca%20href='https://aka.ms/chromedebu
              gging'%20target='_blank'%3ELearn%20more%20about%20Chrome%20debugging%20in%20Visual%20Studio%3C/a%3E%3Ch4%
              3E%3Ci%3EYour%20application%20is%20starting...%3C/i%3E%3C/h4%3E%3C/body%3E%3C!--a43b36c9-654f-4ac6-a825-8
              6dab529cb46--%3E"  --remote-debugging-port=64275 "--user-data-dir=C:\Users\justin.dearing\AppData\Local\M
              icrosoft\VisualStudio\15.0_cf8b40b5\WebTools\ChromeUserData_B1BEBFE6_D97D9A83-D0C1-4583-B7FA-995316F620C4
              "

ProcessId   : 38284
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=crashpad-handler --user-data-dir=C:\
              Users\justin.dearing\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_cf8b40b5\WebTools\ChromeUserData_B1BEBFE6_
              D97D9A83-D0C1-4583-B7FA-995316F620C4 /prefetch:7 --monitor-self-annotation=ptype=crashpad-handler --datab
              ase=C:\Users\justin.dearing\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_cf8b40b5\WebTools\ChromeUserData_B1
              BEBFE6_D97D9A83-D0C1-4583-B7FA-995316F620C4\Crashpad --metrics-dir=C:\Users\justin.dearing\AppData\Local\
              Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_cf8b40b5\WebTools\ChromeUserData_B1BEBFE6_D97D9A83-D0C1-4583-B7FA-995316F620C
              4 --url=https://clients2.google.com/cr/report --annotation=channel= --annotation=plat=Win64 
              --annotation=prod=Chrome --annotation=ver=63.0.3239.132 
              --initial-client-data=0x1e0,0x1e4,0x1e8,0x1dc,0x1ec,0x7ffb01b85720,0x7ffb01b85760,0x7ffb01b85738

ProcessId   : 24784
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=watcher --main-thread-id=30348 
              --on-initialized-event-handle=648 --parent-handle=652 /prefetch:6

ProcessId   : 20216
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=gpu-process 
              --field-trial-handle=1476,13650494111419134215,3798386338761244993,131072 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\justi
              n.dearing\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_cf8b40b5\WebTools\ChromeUserData_B1BEBFE6_D97D9A83-D0
              C1-4583-B7FA-995316F620C4" --gpu-vendor-id=0x8086 --gpu-device-id=0x193a --gpu-driver-vendor="Intel 
              Corporation" --gpu-driver-version=22.20.16.4749 --gpu-driver-date=7-24-2017 
              --gpu-secondary-vendor-ids=0x102b --gpu-secondary-device-ids=0x0533 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\justin.dear
              ing\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_cf8b40b5\WebTools\ChromeUserData_B1BEBFE6_D97D9A83-D0C1-458
              3-B7FA-995316F620C4" --service-request-channel-token=82E278E4387AD1A0720CEC16AF70DC34 
              --mojo-platform-channel-handle=1496 --ignored=" --type=renderer " /prefetch:2

ProcessId   : 10876
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=renderer 
              --field-trial-handle=1476,13650494111419134215,3798386338761244993,131072 
              --service-pipe-token=ADD9924CCB03D545CC0E0AA6AAF8683D --lang=en-US --user-data-dir="C:\Users\justin.deari
              ng\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_cf8b40b5\WebTools\ChromeUserData_B1BEBFE6_D97D9A83-D0C1-4583
              -B7FA-995316F620C4" --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --blink-settin
              gs=disallowFetchForDocWrittenScriptsInMainFrame=false,disallowFetchForDocWrittenScriptsInMainFrameOnSlowC
              onnections=true --enable-pinch --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4 
              --enable-main-frame-before-activation --enable-gpu-async-worker-context --content-image-texture-target=0,
              0,3553;0,1,3553;0,2,3553;0,3,3553;0,4,3553;0,5,3553;0,6,3553;0,7,3553;0,8,3553;0,9,3553;0,10,3553;0,11,35
              53;0,12,3553;0,13,3553;0,14,3553;0,15,3553;0,16,3553;0,17,3553;1,0,3553;1,1,3553;1,2,3553;1,3,3553;1,4,35
              53;1,5,3553;1,6,3553;1,7,3553;1,8,3553;1,9,3553;1,10,3553;1,11,3553;1,12,3553;1,13,3553;1,14,3553;1,15,35
              53;1,16,3553;1,17,3553;2,0,3553;2,1,3553;2,2,3553;2,3,3553;2,4,3553;2,5,3553;2,6,3553;2,7,3553;2,8,3553;2
              ,9,3553;2,10,3553;2,11,3553;2,12,3553;2,13,3553;2,14,3553;2,15,3553;2,16,3553;2,17,3553;3,0,3553;3,1,3553
              ;3,2,3553;3,3,3553;3,4,3553;3,5,3553;3,6,3553;3,7,3553;3,8,3553;3,9,3553;3,10,3553;3,11,3553;3,12,3553;3,
              13,3553;3,14,3553;3,15,3553;3,16,3553;3,17,3553;4,0,3553;4,1,3553;4,2,3553;4,3,3553;4,4,3553;4,5,3553;4,6
              ,3553;4,7,3553;4,8,3553;4,9,3553;4,10,3553;4,11,3553;4,12,3553;4,13,3553;4,14,3553;4,15,3553;4,16,3553;4,
              17,3553;5,0,3553;5,1,3553;5,2,3553;5,3,3553;5,4,3553;5,5,3553;5,6,3553;5,7,3553;5,8,3553;5,9,3553;5,10,35
              53;5,11,3553;5,12,3553;5,13,3553;5,14,3553;5,15,3553;5,16,3553;5,17,3553;6,0,3553;6,1,3553;6,2,3553;6,3,3
              553;6,4,3553;6,5,3553;6,6,3553;6,7,3553;6,8,3553;6,9,3553;6,10,3553;6,11,3553;6,12,3553;6,13,3553;6,14,35
              53;6,15,3553;6,16,3553;6,17,3553 --service-request-channel-token=ADD9924CCB03D545CC0E0AA6AAF8683D 
              --renderer-client-id=4 --mojo-platform-channel-handle=2696 /prefetch:1

ProcessId   : 17564
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=utility 
              --field-trial-handle=1476,13650494111419134215,3798386338761244993,131072 --lang=en-US 
              --service-sandbox-type=utility --user-data-dir="C:\Users\justin.dearing\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStu
              dio\15.0_cf8b40b5\WebTools\ChromeUserData_B1BEBFE6_D97D9A83-D0C1-4583-B7FA-995316F620C4" 
              --service-request-channel-token=ADFC87A17EA167684C81F26EC064A7D5 --mojo-platform-channel-handle=3620 
              --ignored=" --type=renderer " /prefetch:8

ProcessId   : 39788
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check  
              "data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3Chead%3E%3C/head%3E%3Cbody%3E%3Cstyle%3Ebody%7Bmargin:25px;font:16px%20ca
              libri,'segoe%20ui'%7D%3C/style%3E%3Ch3%3EChrome%20script%20debugging%20in%20Visual%20Studio%20is%20enable
              d%3C/h3%3E%3Cul%3E%3Cli%3ESet%20breakpoints%20in%20JavaScript/TypeScript%20in%20Visual%20Studio%3C/li%3E%
              3Cli%3EAutomatically%20break%20on%20script%20errors%3C/li%3E%3Cli%3EOpening%20developer%20tools%20in%20Ch
              rome%20stops%20the%20script%20debugging%20session%3C/li%3E%3C/ul%3E%3Ca%20href='https://aka.ms/chromedebu
              gging'%20target='_blank'%3ELearn%20more%20about%20Chrome%20debugging%20in%20Visual%20Studio%3C/a%3E%3Ch4%
              3E%3Ci%3EYour%20application%20is%20starting...%3C/i%3E%3C/h4%3E%3C/body%3E%3C!--0b9eee99-1dba-447e-844c-2
              a8cd0109b81--%3E"  --remote-debugging-port=64341 "--user-data-dir=C:\Users\justin.dearing\AppData\Local\M
              icrosoft\VisualStudio\15.0_cf8b40b5\WebTools\ChromeUserData_B1BEBFE6_4EE129EE-51D5-41C6-9273-B23F70292D3A
              "

ProcessId   : 35380
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=crashpad-handler --user-data-dir=C:\
              Users\justin.dearing\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_cf8b40b5\WebTools\ChromeUserData_B1BEBFE6_
              4EE129EE-51D5-41C6-9273-B23F70292D3A /prefetch:7 --monitor-self-annotation=ptype=crashpad-handler --datab
              ase=C:\Users\justin.dearing\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_cf8b40b5\WebTools\ChromeUserData_B1
              BEBFE6_4EE129EE-51D5-41C6-9273-B23F70292D3A\Crashpad --metrics-dir=C:\Users\justin.dearing\AppData\Local\
              Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_cf8b40b5\WebTools\ChromeUserData_B1BEBFE6_4EE129EE-51D5-41C6-9273-B23F70292D3
              A --url=https://clients2.google.com/cr/report --annotation=channel= --annotation=plat=Win64 
              --annotation=prod=Chrome --annotation=ver=63.0.3239.132 
              --initial-client-data=0x1e0,0x1e4,0x1e8,0x1dc,0x1ec,0x7ffb01b85720,0x7ffb01b85760,0x7ffb01b85738

ProcessId   : 17104
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=watcher --main-thread-id=5852 
              --on-initialized-event-handle=644 --parent-handle=648 /prefetch:6

ProcessId   : 17968
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=gpu-process 
              --field-trial-handle=1428,3065080944718534067,580319802844548307,131072 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\justin.
              dearing\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_cf8b40b5\WebTools\ChromeUserData_B1BEBFE6_4EE129EE-51D5
              -41C6-9273-B23F70292D3A" --gpu-vendor-id=0x8086 --gpu-device-id=0x193a --gpu-driver-vendor="Intel 
              Corporation" --gpu-driver-version=22.20.16.4749 --gpu-driver-date=7-24-2017 
              --gpu-secondary-vendor-ids=0x102b --gpu-secondary-device-ids=0x0533 --user-data-dir="C:\Users\justin.dear
              ing\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_cf8b40b5\WebTools\ChromeUserData_B1BEBFE6_4EE129EE-51D5-41C
              6-9273-B23F70292D3A" --service-request-channel-token=737996187C3544E7EBA58E9ACA801A7B 
              --mojo-platform-channel-handle=1468 --ignored=" --type=renderer " /prefetch:2

ProcessId   : 29440
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=renderer 
              --field-trial-handle=1428,3065080944718534067,580319802844548307,131072 
              --service-pipe-token=2E60CA09D9FE788066331C313DD6EA18 --lang=en-US --user-data-dir="C:\Users\justin.deari
              ng\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_cf8b40b5\WebTools\ChromeUserData_B1BEBFE6_4EE129EE-51D5-41C6
              -9273-B23F70292D3A" --enable-offline-auto-reload --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --blink-settin
              gs=disallowFetchForDocWrittenScriptsInMainFrame=false,disallowFetchForDocWrittenScriptsInMainFrameOnSlowC
              onnections=true --enable-pinch --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4 
              --enable-main-frame-before-activation --enable-gpu-async-worker-context --content-image-texture-target=0,
              0,3553;0,1,3553;0,2,3553;0,3,3553;0,4,3553;0,5,3553;0,6,3553;0,7,3553;0,8,3553;0,9,3553;0,10,3553;0,11,35
              53;0,12,3553;0,13,3553;0,14,3553;0,15,3553;0,16,3553;0,17,3553;1,0,3553;1,1,3553;1,2,3553;1,3,3553;1,4,35
              53;1,5,3553;1,6,3553;1,7,3553;1,8,3553;1,9,3553;1,10,3553;1,11,3553;1,12,3553;1,13,3553;1,14,3553;1,15,35
              53;1,16,3553;1,17,3553;2,0,3553;2,1,3553;2,2,3553;2,3,3553;2,4,3553;2,5,3553;2,6,3553;2,7,3553;2,8,3553;2
              ,9,3553;2,10,3553;2,11,3553;2,12,3553;2,13,3553;2,14,3553;2,15,3553;2,16,3553;2,17,3553;3,0,3553;3,1,3553
              ;3,2,3553;3,3,3553;3,4,3553;3,5,3553;3,6,3553;3,7,3553;3,8,3553;3,9,3553;3,10,3553;3,11,3553;3,12,3553;3,
              13,3553;3,14,3553;3,15,3553;3,16,3553;3,17,3553;4,0,3553;4,1,3553;4,2,3553;4,3,3553;4,4,3553;4,5,3553;4,6
              ,3553;4,7,3553;4,8,3553;4,9,3553;4,10,3553;4,11,3553;4,12,3553;4,13,3553;4,14,3553;4,15,3553;4,16,3553;4,
              17,3553;5,0,3553;5,1,3553;5,2,3553;5,3,3553;5,4,3553;5,5,3553;5,6,3553;5,7,3553;5,8,3553;5,9,3553;5,10,35
              53;5,11,3553;5,12,3553;5,13,3553;5,14,3553;5,15,3553;5,16,3553;5,17,3553;6,0,3553;6,1,3553;6,2,3553;6,3,3
              553;6,4,3553;6,5,3553;6,6,3553;6,7,3553;6,8,3553;6,9,3553;6,10,3553;6,11,3553;6,12,3553;6,13,3553;6,14,35
              53;6,15,3553;6,16,3553;6,17,3553 --service-request-channel-token=2E60CA09D9FE788066331C313DD6EA18 
              --renderer-client-id=4 --mojo-platform-channel-handle=2724 /prefetch:1

ProcessId   : 15084
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=utility 
              --field-trial-handle=1428,3065080944718534067,580319802844548307,131072 --lang=en-US 
              --service-sandbox-type=utility --user-data-dir="C:\Users\justin.dearing\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStu
              dio\15.0_cf8b40b5\WebTools\ChromeUserData_B1BEBFE6_4EE129EE-51D5-41C6-9273-B23F70292D3A" 
              --service-request-channel-token=3D0651C7E9966DF2088619EA6609F4F0 --mojo-platform-channel-handle=3588 
              --ignored=" --type=renderer " /prefetch:8

ProcessId   : 35200
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=renderer 
              --field-trial-handle=1456,10619170367124795314,15493821474693019085,131072 --disable-databases 
              --service-pipe-token=382A3E80A979F18173360DD969037F1D --lang=en-US --enable-offline-auto-reload 
              --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --blink-settings=disallowFetchForDocWrittenScriptsInMainFrame=f
              alse,disallowFetchForDocWrittenScriptsInMainFrameOnSlowConnections=true --enable-pinch 
              --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation 
              --enable-gpu-async-worker-context --content-image-texture-target=0,0,3553;0,1,3553;0,2,3553;0,3,3553;0,4,
              3553;0,5,3553;0,6,3553;0,7,3553;0,8,3553;0,9,3553;0,10,3553;0,11,3553;0,12,3553;0,13,3553;0,14,3553;0,15,
              3553;0,16,3553;0,17,3553;1,0,3553;1,1,3553;1,2,3553;1,3,3553;1,4,3553;1,5,3553;1,6,3553;1,7,3553;1,8,3553
              ;1,9,3553;1,10,3553;1,11,3553;1,12,3553;1,13,3553;1,14,3553;1,15,3553;1,16,3553;1,17,3553;2,0,3553;2,1,35
              53;2,2,3553;2,3,3553;2,4,3553;2,5,3553;2,6,3553;2,7,3553;2,8,3553;2,9,3553;2,10,3553;2,11,3553;2,12,3553;
              2,13,3553;2,14,3553;2,15,3553;2,16,3553;2,17,3553;3,0,3553;3,1,3553;3,2,3553;3,3,3553;3,4,3553;3,5,3553;3
              ,6,3553;3,7,3553;3,8,3553;3,9,3553;3,10,3553;3,11,3553;3,12,3553;3,13,3553;3,14,3553;3,15,3553;3,16,3553;
              3,17,3553;4,0,3553;4,1,3553;4,2,3553;4,3,3553;4,4,3553;4,5,3553;4,6,3553;4,7,3553;4,8,3553;4,9,3553;4,10,
              3553;4,11,3553;4,12,3553;4,13,3553;4,14,3553;4,15,3553;4,16,3553;4,17,3553;5,0,3553;5,1,3553;5,2,3553;5,3
              ,3553;5,4,3553;5,5,3553;5,6,3553;5,7,3553;5,8,3553;5,9,3553;5,10,3553;5,11,3553;5,12,3553;5,13,3553;5,14,
              3553;5,15,3553;5,16,3553;5,17,3553;6,0,3553;6,1,3553;6,2,3553;6,3,3553;6,4,3553;6,5,3553;6,6,3553;6,7,355
              3;6,8,3553;6,9,3553;6,10,3553;6,11,3553;6,12,3553;6,13,3553;6,14,3553;6,15,3553;6,16,3553;6,17,3553 
              --service-request-channel-token=382A3E80A979F18173360DD969037F1D --renderer-client-id=25 
              --mojo-platform-channel-handle=7584 /prefetch:1

ProcessId   : 23792
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=renderer 
              --field-trial-handle=1456,10619170367124795314,15493821474693019085,131072 --disable-databases 
              --service-pipe-token=156F3EF64699A601618498BF9C88211E --lang=en-US --enable-offline-auto-reload 
              --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --blink-settings=disallowFetchForDocWrittenScriptsInMainFrame=f
              alse,disallowFetchForDocWrittenScriptsInMainFrameOnSlowConnections=true --enable-pinch 
              --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation 
              --enable-gpu-async-worker-context --content-image-texture-target=0,0,3553;0,1,3553;0,2,3553;0,3,3553;0,4,
              3553;0,5,3553;0,6,3553;0,7,3553;0,8,3553;0,9,3553;0,10,3553;0,11,3553;0,12,3553;0,13,3553;0,14,3553;0,15,
              3553;0,16,3553;0,17,3553;1,0,3553;1,1,3553;1,2,3553;1,3,3553;1,4,3553;1,5,3553;1,6,3553;1,7,3553;1,8,3553
              ;1,9,3553;1,10,3553;1,11,3553;1,12,3553;1,13,3553;1,14,3553;1,15,3553;1,16,3553;1,17,3553;2,0,3553;2,1,35
              53;2,2,3553;2,3,3553;2,4,3553;2,5,3553;2,6,3553;2,7,3553;2,8,3553;2,9,3553;2,10,3553;2,11,3553;2,12,3553;
              2,13,3553;2,14,3553;2,15,3553;2,16,3553;2,17,3553;3,0,3553;3,1,3553;3,2,3553;3,3,3553;3,4,3553;3,5,3553;3
              ,6,3553;3,7,3553;3,8,3553;3,9,3553;3,10,3553;3,11,3553;3,12,3553;3,13,3553;3,14,3553;3,15,3553;3,16,3553;
              3,17,3553;4,0,3553;4,1,3553;4,2,3553;4,3,3553;4,4,3553;4,5,3553;4,6,3553;4,7,3553;4,8,3553;4,9,3553;4,10,
              3553;4,11,3553;4,12,3553;4,13,3553;4,14,3553;4,15,3553;4,16,3553;4,17,3553;5,0,3553;5,1,3553;5,2,3553;5,3
              ,3553;5,4,3553;5,5,3553;5,6,3553;5,7,3553;5,8,3553;5,9,3553;5,10,3553;5,11,3553;5,12,3553;5,13,3553;5,14,
              3553;5,15,3553;5,16,3553;5,17,3553;6,0,3553;6,1,3553;6,2,3553;6,3,3553;6,4,3553;6,5,3553;6,6,3553;6,7,355
              3;6,8,3553;6,9,3553;6,10,3553;6,11,3553;6,12,3553;6,13,3553;6,14,3553;6,15,3553;6,16,3553;6,17,3553 
              --service-request-channel-token=156F3EF64699A601618498BF9C88211E --renderer-client-id=31 
              --mojo-platform-channel-handle=10212 /prefetch:1

ProcessId   : 20260
CommandLine : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=renderer 
              --field-trial-handle=1456,10619170367124795314,15493821474693019085,131072 --disable-databases 
              --service-pipe-token=532ED875E6F370AE47E11790881E9553 --lang=en-US --enable-offline-auto-reload 
              --enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only --blink-settings=disallowFetchForDocWrittenScriptsInMainFrame=f
              alse,disallowFetchForDocWrittenScriptsInMainFrameOnSlowConnections=true --enable-pinch 
              --device-scale-factor=1 --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation 
              --enable-gpu-async-worker-context --content-image-texture-target=0,0,3553;0,1,3553;0,2,3553;0,3,3553;0,4,
              3553;0,5,3553;0,6,3553;0,7,3553;0,8,3553;0,9,3553;0,10,3553;0,11,3553;0,12,3553;0,13,3553;0,14,3553;0,15,
              3553;0,16,3553;0,17,3553;1,0,3553;1,1,3553;1,2,3553;1,3,3553;1,4,3553;1,5,3553;1,6,3553;1,7,3553;1,8,3553
              ;1,9,3553;1,10,3553;1,11,3553;1,12,3553;1,13,3553;1,14,3553;1,15,3553;1,16,3553;1,17,3553;2,0,3553;2,1,35
              53;2,2,3553;2,3,3553;2,4,3553;2,5,3553;2,6,3553;2,7,3553;2,8,3553;2,9,3553;2,10,3553;2,11,3553;2,12,3553;
              2,13,3553;2,14,3553;2,15,3553;2,16,3553;2,17,3553;3,0,3553;3,1,3553;3,2,3553;3,3,3553;3,4,3553;3,5,3553;3
              ,6,3553;3,7,3553;3,8,3553;3,9,3553;3,10,3553;3,11,3553;3,12,3553;3,13,3553;3,14,3553;3,15,3553;3,16,3553;
              3,17,3553;4,0,3553;4,1,3553;4,2,3553;4,3,3553;4,4,3553;4,5,3553;4,6,3553;4,7,3553;4,8,3553;4,9,3553;4,10,
              3553;4,11,3553;4,12,3553;4,13,3553;4,14,3553;4,15,3553;4,16,3553;4,17,3553;5,0,3553;5,1,3553;5,2,3553;5,3
              ,3553;5,4,3553;5,5,3553;5,6,3553;5,7,3553;5,8,3553;5,9,3553;5,10,3553;5,11,3553;5,12,3553;5,13,3553;5,14,
              3553;5,15,3553;5,16,3553;5,17,3553;6,0,3553;6,1,3553;6,2,3553;6,3,3553;6,4,3553;6,5,3553;6,6,3553;6,7,355
              3;6,8,3553;6,9,3553;6,10,3553;6,11,3553;6,12,3553;6,13,3553;6,14,3553;6,15,3553;6,16,3553;6,17,3553 
              --service-request-channel-token=532ED875E6F370AE47E11790881E9553 --renderer-client-id=32 
              --mojo-platform-channel-handle=9832 /prefetch:1
```

Is there a simple way to know what Pid to kill to close an incognito tab? Perhaps a simple way to associate url with pid?

Comment: Good question. To find the PID related to a URL, use `Where-Object` (alias `?`). `Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'chrome.exe'" | Select ProcessId,CommandLine| ? { $_.CommandLine -like '*google.com*' } | fl`

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of caveats, but you can kind of do this.

Unfortunately, the command line is not very enlightening when it comes to the URL of the tab it manages. Chrome has a task manager (under "more tools" in the menu), so there clearly is a mapping of tabs to processes somewhere, but it's probably inside one of the Chrome processes and not readily accessible. New Chrome processes appear to get their configuration through some form of [inter-process communication](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/inter-process-communication), hence the `--service-pipe-token` switch, rather than through the command line only.

I did, however, notice a switch that distinguishes incognito processes from normal ones: `--disable-databases`. [Technically](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/public/common/content_switches.cc?q=disable-databases&sq=package:chromium&l=119) it "disables HTML5 DB support", so if the parent process is explicitly given the flag, non-incognito processes would also have it, but otherwise it [is indeed added](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/browser/renderer_host/render_process_host_impl.cc?sq=package:chromium&l=2757) just for incognito processes. Therefore, you can use this PowerShell command:

```
gwmi win32_process | ? {$_.Name -eq 'chrome.exe' -and $_.CommandLine.Contains('--disable-databases')} | % {kill -Id $_.ProcessId}
```

While this does indeed stop all incognito processes, it doesn't necessarily close the incognito window or tabs. When I tried it, all incognito tabs became error pages but stuck around. Alas, this seems to be the best we can do.

Comment: This kind of solves my problem in the sense I want to close these tabs because there was an infinite loop in javascript that caused chrome not to respond to Ctrl+w or pressing the X to close the tab. Once I have the error tab, its possible to close them. I'll look into tracing parent PIDs when I have the time.